# How to identify cause of random poweroff on linux laptop?

Tags: linux, hardware, shutdown, crash

My laptop (thinkpad 13, ~6 years old) has run perfectly since I bought it new, and still does when on AC power.

I started getting random "crashes" a few months ago, only while on battery. The crash is more like an instant power-off,
with no visible warning, it looks like if I pulled the AC plug with no battery installed. I am looking for tips on how
to diagnose this and hopefully solve it.

What I (think I) know so far:

- I don't remember exactly when this started
- it only happens on battery, so I first thought the battery was dead. I'm not really sure how to go about testing this
  in detail.
- but I also don't believe it is caused by a peak in power draw because it can happen even when the computer is doing
  little work (but I have no measurable proof of this).
- I thought of a mechanical problem that could be caused by vibrations/movement, as I had the problem on public
  transport, but shaking/moving the laptop (reasonably) while on AC power never caused a crash.
- I've not been able to spot a specific time between crashes.
- it seems to happen a few minutes after the laptop wakes from suspend-to-ram (which I use most of the time), but I've
  also seen it crash again the same way after I restart the laptop following such a crash, so I'd be tempted to think
  it's not related to the wake from suspend-to-ram process. In some cases, the second crash happened during boot, but I
  can't confirm precisely at what point.
- it does not seem to be heat related in the sense that the machine isn't particularly hot when it happens.
- I ran memtest on the machine after the crash occurred a few times, but no errors were found.
- I run debian unstable, `uname -a` says: `Linux mylaptophostname 5.15.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.15.5-2 (2021-12-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux` but I have upgraded several kernels since this started, and the crash is still present.

Logs around the time of the latest crash (which happened about 5 minutes after waking
from suspend-to-ram) in `/var/log/syslog` show nothing obvious:

```
Jan 17 08:58:19 mylaptophostname nextdns[1476376]: Connected <some ip address> (con=4ms tls=5ms, TCP, TLS13)
Jan 17 08:59:02 mylaptophostname nextdns[1476376]: Connected <some ip address> (con=6ms tls=5ms, TCP, TLS13)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Jan
17 09:02:10 mylaptophostname systemd-modules-load[484]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

The line of garbled characters tells me that it's probably a hardware issue.

In `/var/log/messages` at the same time:

```
Jan 17 08:55:18 mylaptophostname kernel: [64219.674324] wlp3s0: associated
Jan 17 08:55:18 mylaptophostname kernel: [64219.732906] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
<crash happened here around 09:00, so nothing logged for almost 5 minutes>
Jan 17 09:02:10 mylaptophostname mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Jan 17 09:02:10 mylaptophostname mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
```

Are there any other checks I can perform to try and identify the cause of the problem?

EDIT:

As per @felixjn 's questions below:

- `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design` -> `42010000`
- `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full` -> `33390000`
- the laptop does boot from battery, but not everytime (it crashed and rebooted this morning while I was writing this question on battery)

Comment: I suspect your battery is dead or dying. If the laptop works fine when using AC power, there can be no other reason.

Comment: You can check the current battery capacity and the by-design capacity in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full` and `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design` (values in `µWh`) - what are the numbers? Also: does the laptop boot from battery after a crash?

Comment: @FelixJN I edited the question as per your suggestions. The battery then has 79% of its original full capacity left, if I understand correctly. I'm not sure how to interpret this further. is there some sort of test I could run to check the battery?

Comment: @LaurentS very old batteries may misreport their capacity and may behave erratically.

Comment: I also use Lenovo 13 Gen 2 (Type 20J2)  and I've been observing the same issue after around 6 years. It seems that after that long the battery is misreporting remaining charge level and do a poweroff without a warning at around 40%. For me the issue was solved by replacing the battery (Lenovo brand). Compatible types (part numbers): 01AV436, 01AV437.